# Spring Data MongoDB Converter not getting registered

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a setup of multiple MongoDB configuration. Here is the configuration class

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MongoConfigProperties.class)
public class MultipleMongoConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultipleMongoConfig.class);

    private final MongoConfigProperties mongoProperties;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "sysdiagMongoTemplate")
    public MongoOperations sysdiagMongoTemplate() {
        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(sysdiagFactory(mongoProperties.getSysdiag())),
                new MongoMappingContext());

        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new AggregationResultReadConverter());

        mappingMongoConverter.setCustomConversions(new CustomConversions(CustomConversions.StoreConversions.NONE, converters));
        mappingMongoConverter.afterPropertiesSet();
        boolean canConvert = mappingMongoConverter.getConversionService().canConvert(Document.class, AggregationResult.class);
        mappingMongoConverter.afterPropertiesSet();
        logger.info("canConvertFromDocumentToAggResult:: " + canConvert); //gives TRUE

        return new MongoTemplate(sysdiagFactory(this.mongoProperties.getSysdiag()), mappingMongoConverter);
    }

    @Bean(name = "monitoringMongoTemplate")
    public MongoOperations monitoringMongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(monitoringFactory(this.mongoProperties.getMonitoring()));
    }

    public MongoDbFactory sysdiagFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort()),
                mongo.getDatabase());
    }

    public MongoDbFactory monitoringFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(mongo.getHost(), mongo.getPort()),
                mongo.getDatabase());
    }
}
```

Here is the read converter class (I only require reading from MongoDB). We have dynamic keys in the document due to which I need to convert them into a Map

```
public class AggregationResultReadConverter implements Converter<Document, AggregationResult> {
    @Override
    public AggregationResult convert(Document source) {
        AggregationResult aggregationResult = new AggregationResult();
        aggregationResult.setData(new HashMap());
        for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : source.entrySet()){
            if(entry.getKey().matches("[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]")){
                aggregationResult.getData().put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return aggregationResult;
    }
}
```

Here is the mapping configuration for one of the MongoDB database

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.hns.services.restapi.db.mongo.sysdiag.entity", "com.hns.services.restapi.db.mongo.sysdiag.repo"}, mongoTemplateRef = "sysdiagMongoTemplate")
public class SysdiagMongoConfig {
}
```

And here is the repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface AggregationResultRepository extends MongoRepository<AggregationResult, ObjectId> {
    @Query("{ TIME: {$gte : ?0, $lt: ?1}}")
    List<AggregationResult> findInTimeRange(Long startTime, Long endTime);
}
```

When I query using AggregationResultRepository, I expect the converter code to be executed so that I can convert the fields and put them in the Entity (Document) class object as per the logic. The query is going fine as I saw in the debug logs and I see an output but the converter is not getting called.

The converted is getting registered with the mongo template as the canConvertFromDocumentToAggResult logger gives TRUE. I tried changing the converted from `Document -> AggregationResult` to `DBObject -> AggregationResult` but no luck. Not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54817849/2056178

Comment: I have disabled autoconfiguration for mongodb because I wanted two different DB connections driven by properties. This does not work in my case. Also, there is something similar which I have done in sysdiagMongoTemplate() method of MultipleMongoConfig class