# Converting an epoch to Date with MongoDB and SpringBoot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, serialization

I have a large collection of documents in my db, which has not been maintained very well. Most of the time the createdOn is stored as `"yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ssZ"` pattern, but there's several records in which this same field is somehow stored using an epoch format.

Below are samples extracted using MongoDB Compass as `Default Extended JSON`

Document with no issue

```json
"createdOn": {
    "$date": "2019-05-08T07:41:23.312Z"
  }
```

Document with issues

```json
  "createdOn": {
    "$numberLong": "1678864933943"
  }
```

When querying the documents, Spring (or Jackson, or the Java Mongo driver) retrieves this value as a Double, then attempts to convert it back to my entity which is a Date object.

```java
@Data
public class BaseModel {
    @Id
    @JsonSerialize(using= ObjectIdSerializer.class)
    protected ObjectId _id;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ssZ")
    @JsonProperty("createdAt")
    Date createdOn;
```

This results in the following error being thrown

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Double] to type [java.util.Date]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1032)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1584)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1478)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:450)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:367)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:347)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:250)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:98)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3141)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2788)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2518)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2500)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:856)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:842)

... <omitted further lines, will post if requested>
```

Is there a simple solution that will cater for the 2 (or more) possible date formats that is stored in the db to be retrieved gracefully?

I've tried registering a converter to Spring (using `@Component` with a class implementing `Converter<Double, Date>`) but that didn't work.

I've also tried using `@JsonDeserialize(using= DateDeserializers.DateDeserializer.class)` to no avail either.

Limitations :

1. I would prefer to not modify the Entity data types, so no changing to `LocalDate` or `Instant`as I am concerned of potential side effects as this project is rather huge and the modification for this field is on the `BaseModel` which is the base entity that all other entities extends from.
2. I can't fix the documents. There's way too many and not feasible to patch the data.
3. I can add dependencies if it's required to fix the problem, but updating or removing will also potentially have unwanted side effects.

Additional information (versions and stuff):

1. Spring Boot -> v2.3.6.RELEASE
2. javers-spring-boot-starter-mongo -> v5.10.0
3. mongock-spring-v5 -> v4.3.7
4. mongodb-springdata-v3-driver -> v4.3.7

---

Footnote : I realised the question title may be misleading but I really have no idea how else to describe this problem in a single sentence.

Comment: `
@JsonSerialize(converter = YourOwnSerializer.class)
Date createdOn;
` 
should do the trick. 

`
public class YourOwnSerializer extends StdConverter<Object, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convert(Object createdAt) {
        // instanceof checks for determining if its Double or String
        // do the conversion here and return the Date object
    }
}
`
something like this. Well at least I hope it solves your problem I haven't tested that's why it is a comment not an answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the converter required is on the Mongo repository side. To solve the issue, I had to register a converter to the `MongoCustomConversions`

```java
@ReadingConverter
public class MyCustomConverter implements Converter<Double, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convert(Double source) {
        //handle here
        return handledValue;
    }

}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class ConverterConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
        List<Converter> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new MyCustomConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(list);
    }
}
```

[Reference StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39883134/register-a-customconverter-in-a-mongotemplate-with-spring-boot)